# Using RStudio to find the probability of who wins a soccer match?

Tags: probability, programming

Team A on average scores 2.1 goals/match, Team B on average scores 1.6 goals/match. Using R simulate 1000 realisations of the match and estimate the probability of team A winning, team B winning and the probability of a tie.

So far I have found 1000 simulations for how many goals each team would score in each mach using:

```
queueA = rpois(lambda=2.1, n=1000) & queueB = rpois(lambda=1.6, n=1000)
```

But am having problems marrying up the scores for each game and thus finding the required probabilities.

Comment: Is there a particular step in the assignment that you need help with? I don't think anyone in here is just going to do this whole thing just like that.

Comment: If you have created two vectors of the Poisson values, compare the vectors element-wise to determine the result of each game.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth - what is the code for comparing them, sorry I am new to RStudio?

Comment: Ah, so your question is about code, rather than the mathematics? There are several ways to do it. You could simply loop through the elements and that would be fine here. $\texttt{R}$ often allows you to avoid loops though, using other commands. Do you know about loops from programming class?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth - no first time trying to use code!

Comment: Please fix a typo I missed during my edit: "mach" -> "match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If you have two vectors `queueA` and `queueB` in $\texttt{R}$, try typing

> `sum(queueA > queueB)`

That should return the number of elements in `queueA` that are greater than the corresponding element in `queueB`. You can use this to find the number of games where A beat B.

Comment: Thanks for that, it has worked and just had to divide by 1000.